# TestNG:Cannot find class in classpath, testng.xml

Tags: java, xml, testing, testng

This is my testng.xml file, i named it differently, but it should still work:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >

<suite name="TEST_LINKS">

<test name="TECT на подбор спеца">
    <classes>
       <class name="Podbor_specalista_url_click_test" />
    </classes>
  </test>

  <test name="TECT на клик блога">
    <classes>
       <class name="Blog_url_click_test" />
    </classes>
  </test>

</suite>
```

Now, i get the error, but where do I fix it? 
i want to run the whole test suite consisting of these tests:
[image: jj]

[image: the error itself]

Comment: You need to give the `fully qualified class name` of your class in your testng.xml

Comment: @Arkantos, thanks, i figured it out, now sorted.... !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give the fully qualified class name of the class you want to test in `class` tag, something like this

```
<suite thread-count="5" name="Ant suite" junit="false" annotations="JDK"> 
  <test name="Ant test">  
    <classes> 
      <class name="com.sample.test.MyUnitTest"/> 
    </classes> 
  </test> 
</suite>
```

Comment: Glad to be of help :)